# Adjust the display size of an image in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I want to modify the following code so that the image is sufficiently magnified to see individual pixels (python 3x).

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image   
from IPython.display import display  
width = int(input('Enter width: '))
height = int(input('Enter height: '))
iMat = np.random.rand(width*height).reshape((width,height))
im=Image.fromarray(iMat, mode='L')
display(im)
```

Comment: I want to visualize data as individual pixels. I guess I could write a display function which takes each pixel and expands it into a square, but I don't want to do this if I can just add arguments like "...width=50,height=50..." to the end of an existing function. Also, code for clicking on pixels would be simpler and it would be generally useful for scaling different sized images to a particular output format.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Once you have your image, you could resize it by some ratio large enough to see individual pixels.

Example:

```
width = 10
height = 5
# (side note: you had width and height the wrong way around)
iMat = np.random.rand(height * width).reshape((height, width))
im = Image.fromarray(iMat, mode='L')
display(im)
```

Out: [image: minuscule]

10x larger:

```
display(im.resize((40 * width, 40 * height), Image.NEAREST))
```

[image]

Note: it's important to use `Image.NEAREST` for the resampling filter; the default (`Image.BICUBIC`) will blur your image.

---

Also, if you plan to actually display *numerical data* (not some image read from a file or generated as an example), then I would recommend doing away with PIL or other image processing libraries, and instead use proper data plotting libraries. For example, [Seaborn's heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) (or [Matplotlib's](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)).  Here is an example:

```
sns.heatmap(iMat, cmap='binary')
```

[image: ,---]